# Question on finding an orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

So I have a practice question, and I want to make sure that my understanding of the concept is valid.  This is the text of the question:

> Find the orthogonal complement of the subspace of $ R^3$ spanned by $ 
> \left( 1, 2, 1 \right)^{T}$ and $\left( 1, -1, 2 \right)^{T}$.

OK, so my problem isn't finding the orthogonal complement so much as an uncertainty as to whether my grasp of the concept of span/basis is solid.  The book's answer is

> The orthogonal compliment is spanned by $\left( -5, 1, 3 \right)^{T}$

The answer I arrived at is $\left( -\frac{5}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, 1 \right)^{T}$, while I believe this answer, and an infinite number of multiples of this answer, are correct, I'm not 100% sure on this.  It's also been a common experience in my life to be very much wrong despite my confidence to the contrary.  Could a fellow mathematician confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the space of all vectors that are perpendicular to both $[1,2,1]^T$ and $[1,-1,2]^T$. i.e. perpendicular to the plane that they "span" together. Geometrically that space must be a line, or a one-dimensional vector space.

In order to check your answer, you need to make sure that your $[-\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{3},1]^T$ is indeed perpendicular to both vectors (and then by linearity it will perpendicular to the entire plane that they span). well $$ \left[-\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{3},1 \right]^T \cdot[1,2,1]=0 $$ and $$\left[-\frac{5}{3},\frac{1}{3},1 \right]^T \cdot[1,-1,2]=0 $$ as well, so you're good!